# mod_rewrite does not redirect to my internal url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to solve a mod_rewrite rule for my webshop.

The URL is:  `localhost/myshop/category1/category2/myproduct.html`

The rediret URLshould be: `localhost/myshop/configurator/product/configure/id/1/s/myproduct/category1/5/`

If I try a RewriteRule like this

```
RewriteRule ^myproduct\.html$ http://localhost/myshop/configurator/product/configure/id/1/s/myproduct/category1/5/
```

nothing happens and the redirect will not appear.

What i'm doing wrong?

my rewrite rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /myshop/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^myproduct\.html$ http://localhost/myshop/configurator/product/configure/id/1/s/myproduct/category1/5/
```

I want that myproduct.html redirects immediatly to the configurator link, so i want to implement a RewriteRule

Comment: Try explaining your requirement in more details. Also post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-ordering your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /myshop/

RewriteRule (^|/)myproduct\.html$ /myshop/configurator/product/configure/id/1/s/myproduct/category1/5/ [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: No, doesn't work :-( I think there is no match of the html file

Comment: What URL did you wanter in browser?

Comment: localhost/myshop/category1/category2/myproduct.html should be redirect to http://localhost/myshop/configurator/product/configure/id/1/s/myproduct/category1/5/ but if possible, the link should show the entire URL

Comment: Oh yeah that works!! :-) now i've got a redirect to the new URL... is it possible, to show the entire url instead of /configurator/product/...  ?

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean by that. Are you not getting full URL `http://localhost/myshop/configurator/product/configure/id/1/s/myproduct/category1/5/ [L,NC,R]` in the bowser?

Comment: Yes, true. I've got this URL. But, instead of this URL, can i only hide it by another URL? So, content is from the destination URL and browser shows the url with myproduct.html

Comment: Okay, saw your edit and removed the "R", but I doesn't work. Browser shows the /configurator/ url

Comment: Not just removing R flag I changed the target URL also. Instead of `http://` it starts with `configurator/product` now.

Comment: Now URL won't change in the browser only internally it will be rewritten to `/myshop/configurator/product/configure/id/1/s/myproduct/category1/5/ [L,NC]`

Comment: Hmm sorry, even with /myshop/configurator/ this will not work :-/

Comment: In that case we don't have a choice since it appears that there is some PHP framework running inside `/myshop/` it only works with `/myshop/configurator/product/configure/id/1/s/myproduct/category1/5/` URI

Comment: Ahhh, okay... you mean, in any PHP Code there could be a rewrite?

Comment: What I mean is that you have some PHP framework running in your system under `myshop` folder. That framework only recognizes full URI to load this product correctly.